# TypeScript Setter Compile error but it still does its job?

Tags: javascript, typescript, set

Typescript 3.0.1 gives me a compiling error for my setter inside my class but it still does it's job as it should when I run my JS as you can see on the picture.

Code looks like this :

[image]

Is there a reason for that? How do I get it to compile without the error because it is confusing me as I am learning Typescript.

Comment: Please put your code inline in the question, and not in the screenshot. Also, this is a simple typo: you have omitted the `set X(value: number)` type annotation on your setter, so value cannot be safely compared to 0.

Comment: @FengyangWang It's a little more complex than that; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When a property such as `X` is defined by accessors, the return type of the `get` accessor must be the same as the parameter type of the `set` accessor.  Since you didn't annotate either type, by default TypeScript uses the type actually returned by the `get` accessor, which is the type of the property `x` declared in the constructor, which is `number | undefined` because `x` was declared optional.  Thus, in the `set` accessor, the type of `value` is `number | undefined`, and TypeScript won't let you compare `value <= 0` if `value` can be undefined.

To fix the problem, either change the type of `x` so it doesn't include `undefined` (e.g., by specifying a default value for the `x` parameter in the constructor) or check for `value` being undefined in the `set` accessor.